# How to zip multiple Flux streams with filtering

Tags: java, project-reactor, flux

I have 2 source Flux streams which return streams of all keywords and all dictionaries:

```java
Flux<Keyword> keywordFlux = keywordRepository.findAll();
Flux<Dictionary> dictionaryFlux = dictionaryRepository.findAll();
```

`Keyword` has a reference to a `Dictionary` object like the following:

```java
public class Keyword {
    private String id;
    private String dictionaryId;
}
```

The goal is to have a transformed `Flux<DictionaryTO>` which inside holds all properties of `Dictionary` plus a list of keywords **that belong to the dictionary**:

```java
public class DictionaryTO {
    private String id;
    private Collection<KeywordTO> keywords;
}
public class KeywordTO {
    private String id;
}
```

The question is how to zip/merge these 2 Flux streams in a reactive way without blocking any of the source streams.

Note that `keywordFlux` contains **all** keywords, so some filtering should be applied based on `Keyword.dictionaryId`.

Comment: You’re going to have to cache at least one of those inputs to join them. It’s clear that if you want _all_ the keywords for a dictionary you’re going to have to scan the entire keyword source - unless there’s some more structure here you haven’t included in your problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But even if I do `keywordFlux.cache()` and then `keywordFlux.filter()` inside a `dictionaryFlux.map` - then I would need to perform a blocking to construct a list of keywords for a particular dictionary. Which is not good.

Comment: Don’t see why you’d ever need to block - collect one to a `Mono<Map>>` and you’ll then `flatMap` the other in. As I say, you cannot emit a single dictionary until you’ve seen all the keywords - but you don’t need to block, just suspend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by *boris-the-spider*, I ended up using `.flatMap()` and `.zipWith()`.

1. Create a `Mono<Map>` of keywords (grouped by `dictionaryId`) and cache it because it will be used multiple times later.
2. `flatMap` the `Flux` of dictionaries and `zip` single dictionary with the above map of keywords. Then map "tuple of dictionary and keywords map" to a dictionary with keywords.

**Full solution:**

```java
Flux<Keyword> keywordFlux = keywordRepository.findAll();
Flux<Dictionary> dictionaryFlux = dictionaryRepository.findAll();

Mono<Map<String, Collection<KeywordTO>>> keywordsMapMono = keywordFlux
    .collectMultimap(KeywordTO::getDictionaryId, k -> keywordTOMapper.map(k))
    .cache(); 

Flux<DictionaryTO> dictionaryTOFlux = dictionaryFlux
    .map(dictionaryTOMapper:map) 
    .flatMap(dic -> Mono.just(dic).zipWith(keywordsMapMono))
    .map(tuple -> {
        Collection<KeywordTO> keywordsForDic = tuple.getT2().get(dic.getId())
        DictionaryTO dic = tuple.getT1();
        dic.setKeywords(keywordsForDic);
        return dic;
    });
```